# C# MVC "." Symbol in last position of the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, symbols

I have this problem with C# MVC 4, Error 404 if the symbol "." in last position of the url, this is a authentication API.

http://localhost/WS-Avansys/api/Avansys/Authenticate/4551155/Sannn21.

No problem if the "." is in another position like:

http://localhost/WS-Avansys/api/Avansys/Authenticate/4551155/Sannn.21

Comment: There may be something useful in this thread: https://forums.iis.net/t/1175450.aspx.

Comment: What are you doing with the "." at the end?

Comment: The user is 4551155 and password is Sannn.21

Comment: If the "." is in a value within a query string it shouldn't cause a problem.  someurl?u=4551155&p=Sannn21.

Comment: For what it's worth: be very careful with passwords in urls/query strings, because different components may leak this information to third parties via the referrer headers, browser history, and web server logs.

Comment: I would say this is a very bad design for an API, and especially an authentication API.  You are requesting a resource called `Sannn21.` which for many file systems is the equivalent of `Sannn21`.  In windows, you can not create a file that ends with a `.`